# How to validate text input in reactive form such that error is shown if user enters a number

Tags: angular

I am looking to validate for name field such that if a user enters a number in input field then error should occur.

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          fullName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(70),
           Validators.pattern('may be a pattern to disallow number') ]]
      });
    }
```

html

```
<div *ngIf="c.fullName.hasError('pattern')">Name cannot contain number</div>
```

Comment: Check out https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should be right: /[0-9+-\ ]/

Comment: Sorry its gonna accept only numbers but if you add this pattern ^[a-zA-Z]*$ when its gonna accept only letters

Comment: Yes only english alphabets

Answer (score 0):

You can use Validators.pattern and apply a regex pattern to check if the value is just alphabetic characters

```
  this.form = fb.group({
    userName:[null , [Validators.required , Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]+')]]
  })
```

template

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <div>
        <input type="text" formControlName="userName">
  </div>
</div>
<br>

<ng-container *ngIf="form.get('userName').invalid && (form.get('userName').touched || form.get('userName').dirty)">
<div *ngIf="form.get('userName').hasError('required')">
  Required...
</div>
<div *ngIf="form.get('userName').hasError('pattern')">
  Pattern Not valid
</div>
</ng-container>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-template-n8heyt)